Proving functionally incompleteness by showing $\left \{ \vee \ , \wedge \right \}$ can't be described
The connectives @, $ are defined in the following truth table:
$$\begin{matrix} p &q &p@q &p$q \\ F& F& F&T \\ F& T& F&F \\ T& F& T&T \\ T& T& F&T \end{matrix}$$
The question asks if the set of connectives {@, $}  is functionally complete.
I was able to express negation with the system, but I'm failing to express $\left \{ \vee \ , \wedge \right \}$.
This gave me an indication to try to prove that {@, $} is not functionally complete.
My problem is that I'm not able to properly describe the structural induction hypothesis.
All I'm familiar with is the case that the set of connectives doesn't able to describe negation - for this I only need a single atom.
In the case of the question, it seems that I need two atoms, but again I'm not able to properly describe it. 

Try $(p@p)$p$ for negation - there are other expressions.  Then consider $p$\big((q@q)$q\big)$

@Henry Thank you very much !!!
Is there any intuition you can give on how you came up with this p$((q@q)$q) ?

$p$q$ has three Ts and one F in the truth table, so if you adjust the inputs using negation then you can use it to give $\vee$

$p$ q$ is equivalent to $q\to p$. So once you have negation you can just invoke the functional completeness of ${\to,\neg}$.
